# Cannot use token variable for the first time with other threads

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I created Regex postprocessor to get the token from a certain api and made the variable global using beanshell-assertion(__setproperty()).When I run the script,I cannot use the current token for other threads in that iteration.It uses previously stored variable token.I need to use the current one.Can you give me any solution?.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Move your token extraction logic into [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) - it's being executed before other Thread Groups, this way you will get confidence that the newest token is stored into the JMeter Property.

---

With regards to Beanshell Assertion: [since JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) due to the fact that [Groovy's performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so consider migrating to JSR223 Assertion and use the code like:

```
props.put('your_property', vars.get('your_variable'))
```

Alternatively you can just convert variable into property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty), no scripting is required for this use case.